# Static Framework Issue: +entityForName: could not locate an entity named 'APIContent' in this model

Tags: ios, core-data, frameworks, magicalrecord

Can you please help me to understand how to fix this issue ? I am attempting to add Magical Record along with my CoreData database inside a Static Framework that I can use across multiple projects.

The exception I get is the following:

**+entityForName: could not locate an entity named 'APIContent' in this model.**

Please code being ran within my Model below:

```
(void) insertOrUpdate:(NSDictionary *) objectDictionary {
@try {
NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];

APIContent *product;

//  Check if Object Exists
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id == %@", [objectDictionary objectForKey:@"id"]];
product = [APIContent MR_findFirstWithPredicate:predicate inContext:localContext];

BOOL objectIdNotFound = product == nil ? TRUE: FALSE;

if (objectIdNotFound) {
    product = [APIContent MR_createInContext:localContext];
}

// Import Values from the NSDictionary object
[product MR_importValuesForKeysWithObject:objectDictionary];

[localContext saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    if (success) {
        DDLogCInfo(@"Object saved successfully.");
    } else {
        DDLogError(@"Object NOT saved successfully");
    }
}];
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
DDLogError(@"Class: %@ Function: %s at Line: %d \n Exception: %@", [self class], func, LINE, exception);
}

}
```

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 3):

May be here is a problem with bundle? Try to load your `NSManagedObjectModel` by using this method:

```
[MagicalRecord setDefaultModelFromClass:[self class]];
```

I got same error when I was implementing Unit Test for CoreData.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on one of my project and the cause was that I didn't had the entity added to the `.xcdatamodeld` file.

So make sure that the you have an entity called `APIContent` in your `.xcdatamodeld`

Also make sure when you add an entity to your `.xcdatamodeld` that your entity name and class are the same (you can check this in the *Data Mode Inspector* tab)

Answer (score -1):

As well as making sure that your core data entities are named correctly/exist also make sure that your .xcdatamodeld file is named correctly

I ran into the same issue when my .xcdatamodeld was titled 'Model.xcdatamodeld' not 'NameOfProject.xcdatamodeld' as it should have been.

I had set my model name in my coredata implementation (CoreData.m) file to be my project name
so when I compiled and ran the project it was looking for a 'NameOfProject.xcdatamodeld' file but the file was called 'Model.xcdatamodeld'.

If you've made this same mistake, after you've corrected the .xcdatamodeld be sure to uninstall the app from your test device as the previous settings will not update and your corrections will only be implemented when you reinstall  the app on your test device.

( You reinstall the app by just running the project in xcode )

Comment: Why do you need the Core Data model to have the same name as the project, in this case your static library?

Comment: You don't need to have it match the project title necessarily but it does need to match the name in the static file,  I set it as my project name just out of habbit